# Maximum list size that can be passed

Tags: hibernate, hql

There is nothing wrong with the following code. It works fine. I just have a question about passing lists as parameters in HQL. I am using the IN clause in an HQL query like this:

```
AND l.creditGlCode IN (?3)
```

Then setting the parameter like this:

```
aQuery.setParameter(3, glCodes);
```

The HashSet `glcodes` contains strings. What is the maximum size that glcodes can be when passing it as a parameter in HQL? I remember reading somewhere that there is a limit but through countless number of google searches I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help. 
https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1123

Comment: link down, some text would have helped